# ActiveRecord default indexes

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

Does Rails (v3) create an index on the id column by default, or do I have to add the line

`"add_index :table, :id, :unique => true"`

into the migration file?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

ActiveRecord requires that every table has a primary key. It is called "id" by default. You don't need to add it in your migrations.

If you are creating a reference to another table, you will need to create the reference columns somewhat manually. You can either do `t.integer :user_id` or (my preference) `t.belongs_to :user`. The latter is slower, though, because Rails will invoke ActiveRecord to determine what to call the user reference column.

Comment: does Rails create an index by default on the id column?

Comment: On the primary id, yes, but it won't do so for reference columns.